# CallKit Swap button No sound

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, callkit, cxprovider

I got a weird problem in my voip app using CallKit.
When I receive another call (y) and hold current call (x), tapping swap button switch to (x) call but with no sound (although I'm reactivating Audio Session).
The weird thing is that when I navigate to the app (make my app enters foreground), the voice became very clear.
I googled a lot and found many people having the same issue but with no answers. Anyone can help?